# how to avoid script tag library cdn links using on host origin index.html

Tags: javascript

I have multiple environments like dev, pre-production, production so based on the environment I need to access library
only one for environment
because I need to change the id value based the host origin while app load

```
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-xxxxxxxxx-x"></script>

<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-xxxxxxxxx-x"></script>

<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-xxxxxxxxx-x"></script>
```

using this lib ,function gtag() will call

```
window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments)};
  gtag('js', new Date());
```

In case I mentioned 3 scripts libs in index.html so function gtag() will call which lib data

Comment: Ever thought of using webpack?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have multiple environments like develop, pre-prod, production so based on the environment I need to place diff ID's with script CDN links,

so instead of hide the lib ,creating the new script CDN links using get the `window.location.host;`

```
        var host = window.location.host;
        var url;
        if (host.includes('dev-something.com')) {
            url = 'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=xxxxxxxxxxx';
        } else if (host.includes('preprod-something.com')) {
            url = 'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=xxxxxxxxxxx';
        } else if (host.includes('something.com')) {
            url = 'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=xxxxxxxxxxx';
        } else {
            url = 'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=xxxxxxxxxxx';
        }
        var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
        var theScript = document.createElement('script');
        theScript.type = 'text/javascript';
        theScript.src = url;
        head.appendChild(theScript);
```

So it's dynamically creating the CDN link with required ID while loading my index file